# Facebook notification sound in OSX: cannot switch off

Tags: macos, system-settings, facebook, notifications

In OSX Mountain Lion I'm getting beeps every time a facebook notification comes in. In System Preferences > Notifications > Facebook i have set my alert style to None. In the list on the left, the text below "Facebook" shows "Badges, Sounds". It gives me no method of turning off Badges or Sounds.

Mail, Skype and others have two additional checkboxes visible: "Badge App Icon" and "Play sound when receiving notifications". Neither of these are visible on the Facebook item.

So it appears impossible to turn off the sounds?

Comment: I was going to post the same question, wtf!!

Comment: found the answer: on www.facebook.com deep in the maze of settings somewhere is a switch to turn off audible notifications of new posts. i seemed to get audio notifications even if I'd closed the facebook tab in my browser, which led me to suspect it was a Mac OS setting. Turning it off on their web site settings fixed the problem.

Comment: Steve, could you please provide a more specific place "deep in the maze of settings somewhere" so that others can find this "switch"?

Comment: This just worked for me today. Notifications is currently on the left sidebar once you're in your account settings. Thanks for clarifying! Maddening that this isn't controlled from within the notification preferences like every other program or service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. Account Settings>Notifications>How You Get Notifications>On Facebook>Play a sound when each new notification is received (UNCHECK the box). So far, it seems to be working. Whew. Thanks, Steve.

Comment: thanks. yoru instructions worked for me. facebook seem to rearrange their preferences pretty often. hopefully this path will keep working for a wile tho.