# Disable Facebook/Hangouts notification sounds within MacOS

Tags: macos, notifications, facebook

Recently, I have been receiving **persistent audio notifications for Facebook Messenger** without having any Facebook-affiliated website open. (Note: this is also occurring periodically for Google Hangouts.) The notifications persist when Chrome/Firefox/Safari are all simultaneously quit, and the notifications occur twice when the offending tab is open.

As far as I can tell, the only way to disable these persistent audio notifications is through Messenger itself. I am not a fan of this solution, and would prefer to disable these notifications from my side. **Is there a way to disable the notifications *from MacOS*, rather than through Facebook?**

This is similar to [Facebook notification sound in OSX: cannot switch off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80326/facebook-notification-sound-in-osx-cannot-switch-off), except that I would like a way to control my audio notifications via my OS, rather than Facebook. I would also like to know what is causing this sound to play, since it is neither browser nor application.

---

First, I went to into System Preferences > Notifications. There are no apparent culprit applications, except my browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari). After disabling the "Play sound for notifications" option on all three browsers simultaneously while the browsers were quit, the notification sound persisted. In System Preferences > Internet Accounts, I had no synced accounts except for iCloud. In System Preferences > Extensions, there was no apparent culprit.

Per [drfrogsplat's response](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83023/318503) on [What is causing this sound on my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82987/what-is-causing-this-sound-on-my-mac), I ran the following command:

```
find / -name "*.m4a" -or -name "*.aiff" -exec echo "Playing {}" \; -exec afplay "{}" \;
```

I was not able to find the Facebook notification sound that was bothering me.

Additionally:

- macOS Mojave 10.14.2
- no installed Facebook applications